# Port number 8001 is used by SYSTEM PID 4

Tags: jetty, port, apache-servicemix, windows-nt

I am using the port number 8001 for jetty but when I run it is giving following error.

```
66 - org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server - 8.1.15.v20140411 | FAILED SelectChannelConnector@192.168.1.35:8001: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

I checked online and I found out how to see if my port is used by some other service. After finding the port number through
 `netstat -a -n -o | find "8001"`
command, I found out that the port "8001" is being used by **system process with PID 4.** I tried to disable the system service in services menu but it doesn't allow me to change anything for this process. How do I find out which application is using my port? is there any way I can find out which particular application is using my port number?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a corporate environment, it might be CcmExec service. By default it uses port 8001.

You can also check `netsh http show servicestate`

Answer (score 0):

Try using TaskList or TList on Windows. It should show the name of the program running.

Related-- have you considered changing ServiceMix's Jetty instance to use something other than 8001?